# Is it possible to copy a video or a different file to a linux sd card?

Tags: linux, debian, sd-card

I am new for this platform. I am using Lichee Pi(Debian LXDE). I want to play a video. So,firt of all i need a video and video player. But my board does not support ethernet or wifi. so, i downloaded a video on my linux computer and i want to copy that video to linux sd card.
Is it possible? Or are there different solutions? I can view the files in linux computer but **it has write protection.**

### Update 1:

I can write file in /usr/local/games.I used **"chmod"** command for this. But how can access this file on Linux LXDE(desktop edition)?

Comment: You need to disable the write protection. Until you've done that you won't be able to write. Or are you talking about a software setting that's stopping you writing to the card? Please provide details.

Comment: Which file system is there? I mean, `df -h` and `mount` could help. There are indeed read only file systems where you can't easily add files into; it is only possible during (re)creation of file systems, but devices using such file systems usually also have additional conventional write-enabled file systems for storing configuration and volatile data; to discover that check `fdisk -l /dev/...` (the device node of your SD card).

Comment: About *"it has write protection"* Are you talking about SD card? If so check this:  [remove write protection](https://www.diskpart.com/screenshot/en/others/others/move-lock-switch-to-remove-write-protection.png).

Comment: after disable the write protection, Is it a correct way to put my own file (video) in the usr folder? i am talking about this file system: https://res.cloudinary.com/practicaldev/image/fetch/s--kjgxTg3h--/c_limit%2Cf_auto%2Cfl_progressive%2Cq_auto%2Cw_880/https://cdn.hashnode.com/res/hashnode/image/upload/v1647000231917/17qYbX3a3.png

Comment: @SpeedyGonzales if by `usr` folder you meant `/usr/` then I would not recommend it , that folder as well as others in the filesystem structure have different purposes. You should add your video file under `/home/someuser/`

Comment: Thank you @EdgarMagallon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Linux on the machine with the card reader, and it will recognize the file system on the SD card. You can also try to forward USB card reader to the virtual machine running Linux.

There are Linux file system support packages for Windows, like ext2ifs, but I don't recommend using them unless you're an advanced Linux user and you can cope with the possible consequences.

Comment: I can view the files in linux computer but it has write protection. How can write? @NikitaKipriyanov